# Heroku React App shows json of database instead of UI?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, heroku

I have a React app deployed on Heroku, it didn't show any Error in the build and the "heroku logs" command doesn't show any error too but my page shows the json of my mongo database instead of the UI with css and react components.

The website run flawlessly locally. Also, I have tried the troubleshooting guides from Heroku page includes specifying correct npm + node version in package.json and adding node_modules to .gitignore.

Page html

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">==$0
      "[{"items":[{"_id":"5c73504f75c5630017b5fba0","task":"TODO 
      1","done":true,"__v":0},{"_id":"5c73514875c5630017b5fba3","task":"TODO 
      2","done":false,"__v":2}]}]"
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error on page console

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'honeyTipsAutopopOn' of undefined
    at h1-main.js:formatted:1478
    at k (h1-vendors-honeypay-main-popover.js:1)
    at Generator._invoke (h1-vendors-honeypay-main-popover.js:1)
    at Generator.e.<computed> [as next] (h1-vendors-honeypay-main-popover.js:1)
    at r (h1-main.js:formatted:1501)
    at h1-main.js:formatted:1508
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "todolist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.14",
    "node": "^10.16.0",
    "npm": "^6.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix 
    client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const items = require("./routes/api/itemRoutes");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/todolist", {useNewUrlParser: true});
mongoose.connect("...", {useNewUrlParser: true});
let port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.use("/", items);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => {console.log("Server started on port " + port);});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>BriansTodos</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any other solution should I try to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The honeyTipsAutopopOn console error relates to the Honey extension on your Chrome browser. This is unlikely to be causing the React error however.

Answer (score 4):

For any one seeing this, not sure if this was solved.

I had this same issue, without any console errors however, the problem was that I had a route in my Express Server that was named the same as a route in my React app. So instead of returning the React route it returned the data from the Express route.

Try and see if you have any route names that might be clashing?